# Mock function not throwing exception in c# unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, moq

Here is my unit test method

```
        [Fact]
        public void DealerSmsStatusTestTest_MustReturnInternalServerErrorIfMockMethodFails()
        {
            //Arrange
            Mock<DBClass.IDealer> mock = new Mock<DBClass.IDealer>();
            var exception = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException));
            mock.Setup(x => x.GetDealerStatus(new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage()))
                .Throws((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)exception);

            DealerSettingController controller = new DealerSettingController(mock.Object);
            
            //Act
            var result = controller.DealerSmsStatus();
   
            //Assert
         /*I will do assertion here*/

        }
```

And here is my controller method

```
public IHttpActionResult DealerSmsStatus()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = _dealer.GetDealerStatus(Request);
                return Json(new Models.Response(
                            Models.ResponseMessages.Success,
                            result)
                         );
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                return InternalServerError();
            }

        }
```

When i debug the test, `GetDealerStatus()` method should return `SqlException` instead it returns **null**. In controller method `var result` always getting **null**. Any suggestions appreciated why it is not working.I want to throw `SqlException` through `GetDealerStatus()`.
Here is debug mode `result` value image

[image]

Comment: `x.GetDealerStatus(new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())` => `x.GetDealerStatus(It.IsAny<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage>())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `It.IsAny<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage>()` instead of `new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage()` at `Setup`. Because you configured your method for concrete instance of `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`, at test it's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the matcher `x.GetDealerStatus(new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())`

`new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage()` creates a new instance of a `HttpRequestMessage` which will not be equal to the `Request` you're passing into `GetDealerStatus` in your SUT.

Normally you'd use something like:

```
x.GetDealerStatus(It.IsAny<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage>())
```

or

```
It.Is<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage>(x => whatever specific equality conditions you want to match on)
```

if you want to narrow the match condition from just 'any'